# How to use multi stage docker image to copy libnss3.so from one image into another

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to use "gcr.oi/distroless/java:8" image to keep my image lightweight. But, when I run the program, I get error :" Caused by FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/x86_64_linux_gnu/linbnss3.so" and "could not initalize NSS" exceptions. Since, I have to use this image, I want to copy this missing file/dependency from another image "FROM openjdk:8-jre-stretch". Please suggest how to copy this dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue itself is not very descriptive, thus I cannot give a concrete answer here, or elaborate on the fact, where did you make a mistake. But I can give you an example based on examples that have been introduced in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM gcr.oi/distroless/java:8
COPY --from=openjdk:8-jre-stretch /location/of/the/file/in/image /your/target/location
# After that, do your own stuff
```

The COPY --from tells Dockerfile to copy the file from some other image. If the image exists in DockerHub, it will be pulled from there to enable the copy. If the image does not exist in DockerHub, then you must have it locally.

Let me know, if you run into any issues when implementing the example that I gave here.

In case the file in not present in the image without additional steps, then you can use multi-stage build. E.g.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM openjdk:8-jre-stretch as builder
# execute some logic that you need to create the file
FROM gcr.oi/distroless/java:8
COPY --from=builder /location/of/the/file/in/image /your/target/location
# After that, do your own stuff
```

The code

> FROM openjdk:8-jre-stretch as builder

starts the build of an intermediary image that you can reference later with a name 'builder'.